# Libgdx Ashley GWT runtime exception : could not find type for class

Tags: html, gwt, libgdx

I've already run my game in desktop and android platform , but GWT i have some trouble.

In my Screen class :

```
pooledEngine.addSystem(new TouchSystem());
```

and in TouchSystem class :

```
public TouchSystem() {
    super(Family.all(TransformComponent.class, TouchableComponent.class).get());
}
```

In my enityClass , I call :

```
TransformComponent transformComponent = pooledEngine.createComponent(TransformComponent.class);
```

i've got exception like

> "Could not find type for class TransformComponent"

.
Sorry for my bad English.
Thanks!

Edit :
TransformComponent class from Common module :

```
public class TransformComponent extends BaseComponent {
public Vector2 position = new Vector2();
public Vector2 scale = new Vector2(1,1);
public Vector2 pivot = new Vector2(0.5f,0.5f);
public Rectangle bound = new Rectangle();
public float rotation = 0.0f;

public TransformComponent() {
}}
```

BaseComponent from Common module:

```
 BaseComponent implements Component, IScript {
public GameObject gameObject;

public BaseComponent() {
}

@Override
public void addToEntity(GameObject gameObject) {
    this.gameObject = gameObject;
}}
```

my Common.gwt.xml :

```
<extend-configuration-property name="gdx.reflect.include" value="mypacket.common" />
<extend-configuration-property name="gdx.reflect.include" value="com.hat.common.gameobject" />
<extend-configuration-property name="gdx.reflect.include" value="mypacket.common.gameobject.component" />
<extend-configuration-property name="gdx.reflect.include" value="mypacket.common.gameobject.component.TransformComponent" />
<extend-configuration-property name="gdx.reflect.include" value="mypacket.common.gameobject.component.TouchableComponent" />
<extend-configuration-property name="gdx.reflect.include" value="mypacket.common.gameobject.script" />
```

My core module gwt:

```
<inherits name="Common" />
<extend-configuration-property name="gdx.reflect.include" value="mypacket" />
```

My html gwt :

```
<extend-configuration-property name="gdx.reflect.include" value="mypacket" />
<extend-configuration-property name="gdx.reflect.include" value="mypacket.common.gameobject.component" />
<extend-configuration-property name="gdx.reflect.include" value="mypacket.common.gameobject.component.TransformComponent" />
<inherits name='BubbleGame' />
```

I've stuck for times :( Any suggestions ?

Comment: Show `TransformComponent.class` code.

Comment: @tgioihan, Have you specify `TransformComponent` class to be available for reflection via the `gwt.xml` files.

Comment: please see my edit.